# How to change Author name list in typo3

Tags: typo3, author

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63DSx.png)

Hello,

I have taken over the website from my colleague, I do not have much programming experience. I am used to wix or wordpress, but not with programming in typo3. I cannot find the option to change the names in the Author name list. I like to add some of my colleagues, so when I post something from them their name is displayed. How do I change or add names to this Author Name list?

thanks

Searching in google I find programme languages I do not understand. Is there a way to just change settings? Is see no option in typo3.

Comment: Could you try to click on the icon on the left side of your image? Then you could see a context menu with "edit". If you click this maybe you can enter the missing title. 
Another possibility is to switch to list view and edit the content here. Your TYPO3 looks a bit older but you find the "list" usually on the left side, see [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/10.4/en-us/ListModule/UsingEffectively/Index.html) for reference.

Comment: By default there are no author records in TYPO3. Must be a separate extension (news, blog, or other...). If you can provide the extension, one can give you a step by step.

Comment: It looks like there are address objects (extension ```tt_address```) listed in your author box. So you could try to find one of the other addresses via the search field in the upper right corner of you TYPO3 backend. If you are able to find one of the other objects, you eventually find the others in the same folder or on the same page. Then you can edit/delete the objects where the names are missing.

Comment: we might give more detailed hints if you provide more information: what version of TYPO3 do you use? In what context does that selection appear? (screenshot of form or page instead of just the field)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The search helped me locate the Authors section.